# Is it possible to show a swt wizard page on the click of finish of the same wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

All I am doing is finish of a wizard.
On click of this, I want to show the last page of the same wizard.

I am trying to do:
getContainer().getWizard().showPage(REFERENCE TO PAGE).

This doesnt seem to work.

If anyone has solved this,
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Praveen S

Comment: What happens currently when you click finish? Nothing? Does the wizard close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

performFinish() can return false, as far as I remember, if you click on finish button and you return false, the wizard remains opened with last page.